# Why does this work for determining if a number is a power of 2?

Tags: bit-manipulation

```
int isPower2(int x) {
    int neg_one = ~0;
    return !(neg_one ^ (~x+1));
}
```

This code works, I have implemented it and it performs perfectly. However, I cannot wrap my head around why. When I do it by hand, it doesn't make any sense to me.

Say we are starting with a 4 bit number, 4:

0100

This is obviously a power of 2. When I follow the algorithm, though, ~x+1 =

1011 + 1 = 1100

XORing this with negative one (1111) gives 0011. !(0011) = 0. Where am I going wrong here? I know this has to be a flaw in the way I am doing this by hand.

Comment: [What makes you think it works?](http://ideone.com/18FWrz)

Comment: This code doesn't detect powers of 2 at all.

Comment: This is not my solution, so I can't explain the thought process behind it. I can't get it to work by hand, yet it is somehow passing about 50 tests on an autograder. I'm simply trying to understand it.

Comment: Possibilities include that you're submitting the code for the wrong question, or that the tests the autograder is using are terrible.

Comment: This is actually `!(~(~x + 1))`, and `~(~a + b)` is one of the definitions of subtractions, that is, of `a - b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To paraphrase Inigo Montoya, "I do not think this does what you think it does".

Let's break it down.

1. ~x + 1

This flips the bits of 'x' and then adds one. This is the same as taking the 2's complement of 'x'. Or, to put it another way, this is the same as '-x'.

2. neg_one ^ (~x + 1)

Using what we noted in step 1, this simplifies to ...

```
neg_one ^ (-x)
```

or more simply ...

```
-1 ^ (-x)
```

But wait! XOR'ing something with -1 is the same as flipping the bits.  That is ...

```
~(-x)
```

3. ~(-x)

This can be simplified even more if we make use of the 2's complement.

```
~(-x) + 0
= ~(-x) + 1 - 1
= x - 1
```

If you are looking for an easy way to determine if a number is a power of 2, you can use the following instead for numbers greater than zero. It will return true if it is a power of two.

```
(x & (x - 1)) == 0
```

Comment: Right, that's what I was getting too. I understand that last line working for values greater than zero. What if I want to get a function that can take any signed integer including zero as an argument and return if it is a power of two? Meaning it would return zero for any negative number or zero.